# How do you output a QR code to the linux cli terminal for scanning?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, scanning, linux-terminal, qr-code

I want to be able to output a QR code to the ubuntu cli terminal where I can scan with my phone. I have a configuration file I want to convert to a QR code so I can scan it vs having to transfer it over a usb drive. Many of the google results only show you how to convert a file to a QR image file, but I want to output to the terminal itself.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the terminal application [`qrencode`](https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/) ([man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/qrencode.1.html)). The command you are looking for is the following:

```
qrencode -t ansiutf8 < myfile_here
```

The **t** option is to specify output type. it can also be PNG for a file or ASCII as ascii format.

Comment: `sudo apt install qrencode`

Comment: `echo "this a string" | qrencode -t ansiutf8

Answer (score 10):

Passing an url inline:

```
qrencode -m 2 -t utf8 <<< "https://superuser.com/questions/1492624/how-do-you-output-a-qr-code-to-the-linux-cli-terminal-for-scanning/1492625"
```

---

To ease the use, with an alias:

```
alias qr='qrencode -m 2 -t utf8 <<< "$1"'
```

The first time:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now, later on, possible usages:

```
qr https://superuser.com/questions/1492624/how-do-you-output-a-qr-code-to-the-linux-cli-terminal-for-scanning/1492625

qr "Hello world"

qr $(cat file.txt)
```

.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a `python` library, look at this GitHub project [qrcodeT](https://github.com/Khalil-Youssefi/qrcodeT).

Install `qrcodeT` simply using:

```
pip install qrcodeT
```

Example usage:

```
import qrcodeT
qrcodeT.qrcodeT('https://github.com/Khalil-Youssefi/qrcodeT')
```

Sample result:
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykiRr.jpg)

Comment: Question doesn't ask python solution.

Comment: @Toto, it doesn't exclude it either, right? It says "*...to output a QR code to the ubuntu cli terminal...*" and the [usage section](https://github.com/Khalil-Youssefi/qrcodeT#usage) actually shows an example of how to use this on the command line. It's cumbersome, sure, but it does answer the question.